# HP C8941 Photosensor wire colors

Tags: wire, photosensor, color

I removed a photosensor from an OLD hp Inkject Printer. The photosensor is called "C8941-80018". I can't find any datasheet online. Does anyone know what wire color is what?
[image]

Comment: Green=0v is ground?

Comment: The version changes may be confusing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U3ub.png but Rohat has the right idea

Comment: I leave you the images of the sensor, I am trying to make a photo switch with a relay and I was looking for information so I hope the images will help you, greetings from Mexico. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBlGF.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/YseiU.jpg

Comment: @Jose Please ask this as a new question. || Use the [ASK QUESTION](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top of each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors differ from module to module. Some modules have Black-Green-Blue instead of White-Green-Red - At least Google Images say so.

The module itself is nothing different from a LED-Phototransistor Combo. According to your drawing, from the top-view, left side is LED (you can verify this by seeing a diode symbol on the topside) and right side is transistor. And the connection should be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdiM6p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From a Google search, you can find a picture from the bottom side of the module. And this picture verifies what I've shown above:

[image]

So;

- Middle (Green) is GND because it's a common connection
- Top (white) is LED's anode (should be positive supply through a resistor)
- Bottom (Red) is open-collector output