# HP C8941 Photosensor operating voltage and circuit

Tags: voltage, motor-controller, encoder, photosensor

I have at my disposal a photosensor (Optical encoder) with "C8941-80018", it has three cables: Black, Green, and Blue.
I want to know the Operating voltage for this optical encoder and a circuit to use it with Raspberry pi (Preferably) or Arduino.

Please find this related question about the same [Photosensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510380/hp-c8941-photosensor-wire-colors).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6YNBA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The device. Image based on @RohatKılıç's answer linked in the question.*

- The LED will be infrared so it will require 10 to 20 mA typically. *V<sub>f</sub>* will be about 1.4 V.
- The transistor will be well capable of pulling down the input to a Raspberry Pi. Either enable the input pull-up resistor or use an external one. 10 kΩ would do the job.