# HP C9017 Photosensor wire colors

Tags: raspberry-pi, motor-controller, photosensor, colour

I have at my disposal a photosensor (Optical encoder) with "C9017-80055", it has three cables: Black, Green, and yellow. I want to know the circuit (GND, VCC, output) to connect it with Raspberry pi, there is a problem if I connect it with raspberry pi without a resistor?.

Please find this related question about the same Photosensor [Photosensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510380/hp-c8941-photosensor-wire-colors) but I'm in trouble to understand.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqWrDO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The component contains an infrared LED and a phototransistor. The case outline is in grey.*

We can see from your photos that the green wire is attached to a trace that goes to both sides of the opto device. This is almost certainly a common ground.

> I want to know the circuit (GND, VCC, output) to connect it with Raspberry Pi, ...

We've got the green. Now you need to figure out the blue and yellow.

> ... there is a problem if I connect it with raspberry pi without a resistor?

There certainly is. If you do that to an LED you will have no current limit. Infrared diodes have a forward voltage of 1.4 V or so. To limit the current to 10 mA (a reasonable choice) you need $$ R = \frac {V_{CC} - V_f}I = \frac {3.3 - 1.4}{0.01} $$ which you can work out. That resistor will do to protect the transistor while you test it too.

Connect green to your Pi ground. Try connecting the yellow to the +3.3 V supply via the resistor. Then look into the slots [using your phone camera to detect the infrared](http://lednique.com/test-equipment/test-infrared-led/) to see if either side lights. If it does then yellow is your LED. If not try powering up the black in the same way.

Comment: i have black green and yellow you mean i connecting the black to the +3.3 V or yellow ?

Comment: Sorry I may have mixed up colours from the other question. Try one first then the other.

Comment: can you edited, please

Comment: You can edit to fix it if you like. It doesn't change the method.

Comment: i connect the black to the +3.3 V yes ?

Comment: green is GND can you tell me about yellow and black sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: I edited the answer. (You shouldn't accept the first answer that comes unless it really solves your problem, but thank you.)

Comment: Thank you so much